# Double content with events manager and Qtranslate on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I'm making a Wordpress site with the Events manager plugin and Qtranslate.
When I display the event page the content will show in the correct language.
But when I use the event/location list or upcoming events widget from the eventsmanager plugin,
It shows the content in both languages.
This is my code in the location list:

```
<li class="event-page-list-item">   
<ul>
    <li class="event-list-title item"><a href="#_LOCATIONURL">#_LOCATIONNAME</a></li>
    <li class="event-list-location item"><a href="#_LOCATIONURL">#_LOCATIONADDRESS</a></li>
    <li class="event-list-location item">#_LATT{email adres}{E-mail niet bekend}</li>

    <li class="event-list-location item"><a href="#_LATT{website}{Website niet bekend}">#_LATT{website}{Website niet bekend}</a></li>           
    </ul>
</li>
```